# How to show that $\theta(A):=A\cup\mathscr{der}(A)$ is a kuratowski operator?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, alternative-proof

Let be $\eta:\mathcal{P}(X)\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(X)$ a function such that:

1. $\eta(\varnothing)=\varnothing$;
2. $\eta(\eta(A))\subseteq A\cup\eta(A)$, for any $A\subseteq X$;
3. $\eta(A\cup B)=\eta(A)\cup\eta(B)$, for any $A,B\subseteq X$;
4. $x\notin \eta(\{x\})$, for any $x\in X$.

So putting
$$
\tau*=\{A\subseteq X: \phi(A)\subseteq A\}
$$
I am trying to prove that the collection
$$
\tau=\{V\subseteq X:X\setminus V\in\tau*\}
$$
is a topology on $X$ equal to $\tau^*$ and such that
$$
\eta(A)=\operatorname{der}A
$$
for any $A\in\mathcal P(X)$.

Well to prove the statement we define
$$
\theta:\mathcal{P}(X)\owns A\rightarrow\big(A\cup\eta(A)\big)\in\mathcal{P}(X)
$$
so that we let to prove that $\theta$ is a Kuratowski operator. So to do this we have to demonstrate that

1. $\theta(\varnothing)=\varnothing$;
2. $A\subseteq\theta(A)$ for any ${A}\subseteq{X}$;
3. $\theta(\theta(A))=\theta(A)$ for any ${A}\subseteq{X}$;
4. $\theta(A\cup{B})=\theta(A)\cup\theta(B)$ for any $A,B\subseteq{X}$.

Well let's start to prove this:

1. first of all we observe that
   $$
   \theta(\varnothing)=\varnothing\cup\eta(\varnothing)=\varnothing
   $$
   so that $1$ holds;
2. then we observe that
   $$
   A\subseteq A\cup\eta(A)=\theta(A)
   $$
   so that $2$ holds;
3. moreover we observe that
   $$
   \theta(\theta(A))=
   \theta(A\cup\eta(A))=
   (A\cup\eta(A))\cup\eta(A\cup\eta(A))=\\(A\cup\eta(A))\cup(\eta(A)\cup\eta(\eta(A)))=
   A\cup\eta(A)\cup\eta(\eta(A))=
   A\cup\eta(A)=
   \theta(A)
   $$
   so that $3$ holds;
4. finally we observe that
   $$
   \theta(A\cup B)=(A\cup B)\cup\eta(A\cup B)=A\cup\eta(A)\cup B\cup\eta(B)=\theta(A)\cup\theta(B)
   $$
   so that $4$ holds.

Well we proved that $\theta$ is a kuratowski operator so we have
$$
\theta(A)=\operatorname{cl}A
$$
that is
$$
A\cup\eta(A)=A\cup\mathscr{der}(A)
$$
for any $A\subseteq X$: could I argue from this that the identity
$$
\eta(A)=\mathscr{der}(A)
$$
holds? if not how to prove it?

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Same title as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3533162/how-to-show-that-thetaa-a-cup-partial-a-is-a-kuratowski-operator – same question?

Comment: No, it si similar but it is not the same question!

Comment: OK. It would be a good idea to link each question to the other.

Comment: Of course we can't infer $B=C$ from $A\cup B=A\cup C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't argue so, because condition 4. was not used, and without that your reasoning would also work for the closure operator $\eta:=\theta$  itself, concluding that closure is always the same as the derived set.
Nevertheless, $A\cup B=A\cup C$ implies $B\setminus A\subseteq C$ and $C\setminus A\subseteq B$, which will be used below.

If $x\in A\setminus \mathrm{der}(A)$, then there is an open $U\ni x$ such that $U\cap A=\{x\}$, then $\eta(A\setminus U) \subseteq \theta(A\setminus U) \subseteq \theta(X\setminus U) =X\setminus U$, which in particular doesn't contain $x$, so by conditions 3. and 4. for $\eta$, we get
$$x\notin \eta(A\cap U)\cup\eta(A\setminus U) =\eta(A)\,.$$

If $x\notin{\rm der}(A)$ then the case $x\in A$ was just concluded, and in the case $x\notin A$, we have $x\notin \bar A=A\cup \eta(A)$, thus again $x\notin \eta(A)$.

These imply $\eta(A)\subseteq {\rm der}(A)$.

For the other direction, we have ${\rm der}(A)\setminus A=\bar A\setminus A\subseteq \eta(A)$ for any set $A$. 
So, let $a\in{\rm der}(A)\cap A$, but then, for $B:=A\setminus\{a\}$, we still have $a\in{\rm der}(B)$, so we can apply the above observation to obtain $a\in\eta(B)$, and conclude by $\eta(A) =\eta(B) \cup\eta(\{a\})$.

Comment: Well  $x\notin \eta(A\setminus U)\cup\eta(\{x\})=\eta(A\setminus U)\cup\eta(A\cap U)=\eta(A\setminus U\cup A\cap U)=\eta(A)$ and so $$\{x\in A\setminus\mathscr{der}(A)\rightarrow x\notin \eta(A)\}\Rightarrow\{x\in A\setminus\mathscr{der}(A)\rightarrow x\notin \eta(A)\wedge x\in A\}\Rightarrow\{x\in A\setminus\mathscr{der}(A)\rightarrow x\in A\setminus\eta(A)\}\Rightarrow A\setminus\mathscr{der}(A)\subseteq A\setminus\eta(A)\Rightarrow A\cap\eta(A)=A\setminus(A\setminus\eta(A))\subseteq A\setminus(A\setminus\mathscr{der}(A))=A\cap\mathscr{der}(A)$$, and form this what can I argue?

Comment: Apparentely I can't argue that $\eta(A)\subseteq\mathscr{der}(A)!$ Then with the other inclusion, that is $A\setminus\eta(A)\subseteq A\setminus\mathscr{der}(A)$, I only proved that$A\cap\eta(A)=A\cap\mathscr{der}(A)$, and form this how could I argue that $\eta(A)\equiv\mathscr{der}(A)$? Could you explain better, please? Then it seems I don't be able to prove the oder implication, excuse me: so could you do it, please?

Comment: I don't understand your first question. My answer shows $\eta(A)\subseteq {\rm der}(A)$ by the contrapositive. If $x\notin{\rm der}(A)$ then either $x\notin\bar A=A\cup\eta(A)$ when $x\notin\eta(A)$, or $x\in A\setminus{\rm der}A$ when $x\notin\eta(A)=\eta(A\setminus U)\cup\eta(A\cap U)$. As for the other direction, I got uncertain.

Comment: So we know that  
$$
x\notin\eta(A\setminus U)\wedge x\notin\eta(\{x\})\Rightarrow x\notin \eta(A\setminus U)\cup\eta(\{x\})=\eta(A\setminus U)\cup\eta(A\cap U)=\eta(A\setminus U\cup A\cap U)=\eta(A)
$$

Comment: and so 
$$\{x\in A\setminus\mathscr{der}(A)\rightarrow x\notin \eta(A)\}\Rightarrow\{x\in A\setminus\mathscr{der}(A)\rightarrow x\notin \eta(A)\wedge x\in A\}\Rightarrow\{x\in A\setminus\mathscr{der}(A)\rightarrow x\in A\setminus\eta(A)\}\Rightarrow A\setminus\mathscr{der}(A)\subseteq A\setminus\eta(A)\Rightarrow A\cap\eta(A)=A\setminus(A\setminus\eta(A))\subseteq A\setminus(A\setminus\mathscr{der}(A))=A\cap\mathscr{der}(A)$$

Comment: Well 
$$\eta(A)\subseteq A\cup\eta(A)=\overline{A}=A\cup\mathscr{der}(A)\Rightarrow\eta(A)=(A\cap\eta(A))\cup(\mathscr{der}(A)\cap\eta(A))\subseteq(A\cap\mathscr{der}(A))\cup(\eta(A)\cap\mathscr{der}(A))=(A\cup\eta(A))\cap\mathscr{der}(A)=\overline{A}\cap\mathscr{der}(A)=\mathscr{der}(A)
$$
is it right?
Well you can't prove the other inclusion?

Comment: Indeed if you prove that
$$
A\setminus\eta(A)\subseteq A\setminus\mathscr{der}(A)
$$
then as soon as shown it turns out that
$$
A\setminus\eta(A)=A\setminus\mathscr{der}(A)
$$
that is
$$
A\cap\eta(A)=A\setminus(A\setminus\eta(A))=A\setminus(A\setminus\mathscr{der}(A))=A\cap\mathscr{der}(A)
$$
and so as soon as shown above it result that 
$$\eta(A)=(A\cap\eta(A))\cup(\mathscr{der}(A)\cap\eta(A))=(A\cap\mathscr{der}(A))\cup(\eta(A)\cap\mathscr{der}(A))=(A\cup\eta(A))\cap\mathscr{der}(A)=\overline{A}\cap\mathscr{der}(A)=\mathscr{der}(A)$$ could you help me, please?

Comment: I updated my answer with the other direction. My original sketch I had in mind for that didn't work. Is the first inclusion clear?

Comment: Well I understeand the first inclusion, that is $\eta(A)\subseteq\mathscr{der}(A)$; but unfortunately in the second step of the proof I don't understeand the passage $x\in\mathscr{der}(B)\Rightarrow x\in\eta(B)$ so could you explain better?

Comment: We start with $a\in A\cap{\rm der}(A)$. Because of the definition of derived point, we get $a\in{\rm der}(B)$ with $B=A\setminus\{a\}$ but $a\notin B$, so we have $a\in {\rm der}(B)\setminus B$ which is $\subseteq \eta(B)\subseteq \eta(A)$.

Comment: Okay, so to summarise step by step we have: $x\in\mathscr{der}(A)\Rightarrow x\in\mathscr{der}(A\setminus\{x\})$ so it result 
$$
x\in\mathscr{der}(A)\cap A\Rightarrow x\in\mathscr{der}(A\setminus\{x\})\cap\ A\subseteq\mathscr{der}(A\setminus\{x\})
$$
but then it result that 
$$
x\in\mathscr{der}(A\setminus\{x\})\wedge x\notin(A\setminus\{x\})\Rightarrow x\in\mathscr{der}(A\setminus\{x\})\setminus(A\setminus\{x\})\subseteq\eta(A\setminus\{x\})\subseteq\eta(A)
$$

Comment: therefore 
$$
\{x\in\mathscr{der}(A)\cap A\rightarrow x\in\eta(A)\}\Rightarrow \mathscr{der}(A)\cap A\subseteq\eta(A)\Rightarrow\mathscr{der}(A)\cap A\subseteq\eta(A)\cap A
$$
and so, since from the first step of the proof we know that $\eta(A)\cap A\subseteq\mathscr{der}(A)\cap A$, we conclude that 
$$\eta(A)\cap A=\mathscr{der}(A)\cap A$$

Comment: so finally we have 
$$\eta(A)\subseteq A\cup\eta(A)=\overline{A}=A\cup\mathscr{der}(A)\Rightarrow\eta(A)=(A\cap\eta(A))\cup(\mathscr{der}(A)\cap\eta(A))=(A\cap\mathscr{der}(A))\cup(\eta(A)\cap\mathscr{der}(A))=(A\cup\eta(A))\cap\mathscr{der}(A)=\overline{A}\cap\mathscr{der}(A)=\mathscr{der}(A)
$$
is it right?